# need to select an array in an array of arrays in c++

Tags: c++

I have an `foo[X][my_array[]]`

I need to store X number of `my_array`.

Another script would be sent `my_array` , this script would be then sent back an array and I need to check the difference.

I could send 5 `my_arrays` and the script would then return 5 arrays
I then need to check to see if each `my_array` I sent is the same as the array I received.(this would be done in a while loop)

while (i<5){
if (foo[i][my_array]!= array)
print an error
}//just an example

`my_array` is sent to the script without been broken up. ie the script takes an array

Earlier I had an `my_array[]` and I could send all values by just sending 
`'my_array'`

Answer: Turns out i can just say foo[i] to select the ith my_array

Comment: Be more specific (is this an STL array?), provide sample code. Specifically, provide the declaration of identifiers you use, and show what you want to do (in pseudo code where you are stuck).

Comment: What do mean by "send an array"?

Comment: Turns out i can just say foo[i] to select the ith my_array

Answer (score 1):

Just use `array[4]` as in

```
void print(const int (&a)[10])
{
    for (auto e : a)
    {
        std::cout << " " << e;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main() {
    int a[10][10] = {
        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        {10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19},
        {20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29},
        {30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39},
        {40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49},
        {50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59},
        {60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69},
        {70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79},
        {80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89},
        {90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99},
    };

    print(a[4]);
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/xpHeK2)